# Difference declaring cursor like variable with @ or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I got this question that I can't find an answer:

In SQL Server, what's the difference between

```
DECLARE CRS_RQS INSENSITIVE CURSOR FOR
    SELECT pRqsMtr FROM dtRqsMtr
    WHERE pRqs = @pRqs
OPEN CRS_RQS
FETCH NEXT FROM CRS_RQS INTO @pRqsMtr
WHILE (@@Fetch_Status = 0) AND (@@Error = 0)
BEGIN

    -- do some stuff...
    FETCH NEXT FROM CRS_RQS INTO @pRqsMtr
END 
CLOSE CRS_RQS
DEALLOCATE CRS_RQS
```

and this?

```
DECLARE @CRS_RQS CURSOR
SET @CRS_RQS = VOID
SET @CRS_RQS = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT pRqsMtr FROM dtRqsMtr
    WHERE pRqs = @pRqs
OPEN @CRS_RQS
FETCH NEXT FROM @CRS_RQS INTO @pRqsMtr
WHILE (@@Fetch_Status = 0) AND (@@Error = 0)
BEGIN

    -- do some stuff...
    FETCH NEXT FROM @CRS_RQS INTO @pRqsMtr
END 
CLOSE @CRS_RQS
DEALLOCATE @CRS_RQS
```

and.. what's the best of the 2 above?

thanks in advance

Comment: *"what's the best of the 2 above"* Neither? Using a cursor is normally far from "best" period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sure you actually need a cursor (it is the wrong choice more often than not), best is `@CRS_RQS` because:

- it automatically leaves out some of the heavier default options from a "normal" cursor; and,
- you don't have to close/declare; it does that automatically.

See this post from Itzik Ben-Gan on why he's switched to local cursor variables:

- [Overlooked T-SQL Gems](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/10/t-sql-queries/overlooked-t-sql-gems#cursor)

And see some of my performance research on the best options to use for a "real" cursor:

- [What impact can different cursor options have?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options)
- [Follow-up on cursor options](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options-2)

The most salient point is to use `LOCAL FAST_FORWARD` unless you know you need different options (all the options are described [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)).

Comment: thank you! but a question: why all of you dislike the cursor? In my stored procedure I need to cycle over a query result.. is there a best way to do this?

Comment: @ghiboz *why* do you need to "cycle over a query result"? SQL Server is optimized for dealing with sets... instead of thinking "I need to do x to every row" think "I need to do x to _all the rows_." There are cases where cursors / loops are required, but generally, they shouldn't be the _desired_ approach to solving a given problem.